# Can't acces docker container by IP address

Tags: routes, containers, docker

I am working on a django app, and I decided to move all my dev into docker containers. I have a small problem:
    Basically, I have 3 containers:
- app (which holds the django code)
- postgres (which holds the database)
- web (which is an nginx that forwards requests coming on port 80 to 8000 which is the port used by django)
    My problem is that I cannot access my website from outside the "app" container, my nginx logs say:

```
2014/12/21 22:22:35 [error] 9#0: *9 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 192.168.59.3, server: _, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://172.17.0.62:8000/", host: "192.168.59.103"
```

So apparently, nginx cannot forward the connexions because the "app" container (192.168.59.103) does not listen for connexions. But that's not true, because I attached to the app container and I tried to make a curl request, but:
- If I do `curl "localhost:8000"`, it works (I get the django Welcome page
- If I do `curl "http://172.17.0.62:8000/"` It does not work
    So, I managed to isolate the problem and run "route" command that shows me:

```
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         172.17.42.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
172.17.0.0      *               255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 eth0
```

Them, I went on the  boot2docker ssh and typed "route" and this is what came out:

```
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         10.0.2.2        0.0.0.0         UG    1      0        0 eth0
10.0.2.0        *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
127.0.0.1       *               255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 lo
172.17.0.0      *               255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 docker0
192.168.59.0    *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth1
```

So apparently I don't have the good routes to my containers, but that is odd, because I didn't touch any of its configs. Anybody has a clue?

Comment: What does your docker run command look like for all of the containers?

Answer (score -1):

A few comments:

> web (which is an nginx that forwards requests coming on port 80 to 8000 which is the port used by django)

If you are using nginx just to forward from 80 to 8080 why not run your app container with -p 80:8080 which have the same effect without an intermediate container.

If you want nginx to be able to able to talk to the app container the app container must be linked to the nginx container using the `--link APP_CONTAINER:ALIAS`switch when running docker run for nginx. Then you can look at /etc/hosts inside the nginx container for the IP at which ALIAS is mapped. Each docker container gets its own IP from the docker bridge and needs to be linked for communication to be possible.

Docker inter-container communication is managed using iptables. run iptables -L to take a look at the routes configured. You should probably not mess with this manually. Linking containers normally manages these things fairly well.

Comment: I am using nginix also for deployment purposes. I know that I can simply map the port, but I need to do this way for my company. The problem is that the routes between the containers are messed up. Each container does not know of its own IP address. If I ping localhost it works, but if I ping by its IP address it doesn't